# google sheet : My conditional formula is suddenly not working

Tags: google-sheets

I've been using this formula a lot and it always works on my other files. But this time i'm confused, i always got error. I'm just using new empty sheet, there's no data at all. Does anyone can spot the problem ? Pls see my screenshot.

```
=countif(A1:A,A1)>1
```

It works on my other files, but i have no clue why it doesn't work on this file. I tried new sheet, but no luck. I close and reopen file, but still the same.

Note : when i use in another new file, it works fine.

Thanks
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

either change locale of your spreadsheet to English-based or use semicolon as argument separator instead of comma:

```
=COUNTIF(A1:A; A1)>1
```